# Get HTTP connection pool from Websphere 6.1

Tags: rest, http, websphere, httpclient

All

I am making REST client calls from an EJB container (IBM Websphere v6.1) and cannot find any way to get a HTTP connection factory from WAS.

---

**Is this possible in WAS 6.1?**

---

*Would expect be able to access this with JNDI so connection pool configuration, socket timeout, connection timeout, connections per URL etc could be centrally managed.*

If not the alternative is to use a Client API such as HttpClient 4.3. But this has its own kettle of fish:

They recommend 'BasicHttpClientConnectionManager': "This connection manager implementation should be used inside an EJB container". However this implies one connection per thread which in an application with many threads will exhaust the resources of the O/S.

The other alternative 'PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager' seems to be a much better fit with much of the required controls, but in the the comments on the the Basic manager it says explicitly that the Pooling manager shouldn't be used in a EJB container managed context. Scanning the code for this it looks like the Pooling manager uses Future from the concurrent library but doesn't appear to directly use Threads.

Any suggestions about the best way forward would be appreciated - some options seem to be:

1. Test with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - with risk of subtle problems
2. Play safe with 'BasicHttpClientConnectionManager' but set short response and socket timeouts to constrain the number of concurrent sockets at the cost of lots of factory overhead. Yuk.
3. Some other way of getting access to the pool of HTTP connections in WAS 6.1.
4. Something else

**Any suggestions for this rather ikky problem would be ideal.**

Please don't suggest upgrading WAS - although future versions ie the WAS commerce version do seem to have a JCA HTTP Adaptor and 8.5 has a built in REST client.

---

---

---

*Please don't publish responses relating to MQ/JMS, JDBC connection pooling or setting up resource adaptors for EIS other than HTTP.*